# Bing map ajax v7 control does not show infoBox 'close' button

Tags: bing-maps, infobox

For some reason this property is ignored.
Below is my code, as you can see i don't use a custom html.
Any idea why?

*edit: i'm using the BingTheme.
the reason i need this button is that for some reason sometimes the infoBox does not close automatically when clicking another place on the map*

```
this.map.entities.push(new Microsoft.Maps.Infobox(currentLocation,
                    {
                        title: location.threatType,
                        description: layer.Options.InfoBoxText + "</br>IP: " + location.IP, pushpin: pin,
                        zIndex: 100,
                        showCloseButton: true
                    }));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Bing Theme module overrides all styles to match the styles that are used by, now older, Bing Maps site. As such customizations, such as showing the close button are disabled. I, personally never liked this module and recommend not using it. You can create a lot more customizations using the control without this module.